# CSS warnings in vendor CSS files?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I have an Angular JS size built with Yeoman using several common Bower packages, such as Select2.

When I load and page, the Console is loading with warnings from these files, such as:

[image]

The Less files are from Bootstrap 3.  ALL of these warnings are due to the CSS using old "filter" parameters for transparency in MSIE.

I don't want to edit vendor css, since this should be pristine and loaded via Bower for each member of my team.  OTOH, it is inconvenient to clog up the console with this.  I know how to not show warnings, but I'd like to see warnings if they exist from my code.

What do you all do it this situation?

Comment: You could rewrite the `console.warn` function.

Comment: In your console, you can click the filter icon in the top left, and use it to show only errors.

Comment: Yes, I know how to filter it out.  Hopefully the final Safari 8 will be less aggressive.